# Finding a value in R that contains a certain string

Tags: r

Is there a way in R to find values in a column that contain a word? For example, I want to find all the values that contain the word "the", where some values of the column are "the_cat" and "the_dog" and "dog"

```
x <- c("the_dog", "the_cat", "dog")
```

Using the example above, the answer would be 2.
I know this is relatively easy to do in Python, but I am wondering if there is a way to do this in R. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
sum(grepl("(?<![A-Za-z])the(?![A-Za-z])", x, perl = T))
```

This gives a sum of 2 on your example.

But let's consider also a slightly more complex example:

```
x <- c("the_dog", "the_cat", "dog", "theano", "menthe", " the")
```

Output:

```
[1] 3
```

Above we're trying to match any `the` that doesn't have another letter before or after (like e.g. `theano`).

You could also add inside the `[]` other things you wouldn't like to match, like e.g. if you wouldn't consider `the99` a word `the`, you would do `[A-Za-z0-9]` etc.

You can also use the above with `stringr`, for example (I've included the exclusion of numbers, so below `the99` wouldn't be counted as a word):

```
library(stringr)

sum(str_detect(x, "(?<![A-Za-z0-9])the(?![A-Za-z0-9])"))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(stringr)
##with a vector
sum(str_detect(c("the_dog", "the_cat", "dog"),"the"))

##In a dataframe

tibble(x = c("the_dog", "the_cat", "dog")) %>%
    filter(str_detect(x, "the")) %>%
    nrow()
```

Answer (score 0):

```r
x <- c("the_dog", "the_cat", "dog") 
stringr::str_detect(x, "the")
#> [1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

Try also:

```
x <- c("the_dog", "the_cat", "dog")
sum(stringi::stri_count(x,regex="^the"))#matches the at the beginning
```

Result:

```
[1] 2
```

Or:

```
   x <- c("the_dog", "the_cat", "dog")
  sum(stringi::stri_count(x,regex="the{1,}"))#matches any the
```